# New input values not recognized after validation error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I have a user control with some fields like a textBox called textBoxNombre

I have some validation annotations like:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Debe escribir el Nombre")]
    public String Nombre { get; set; }
```

This is the simplified code for a button (called buttonAgregar) used to add a new Cliente (Customer):

```
    private void buttonAgregar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cliente = new Cliente
        {
            Nombre = textBoxNombre.Text,
            Apellido1 = textBoxPrimerApellido.Text,
            Apellido2 = textBoxSegundoApellido.Text,
        };

        db.Clientes.Add(cliente);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException exc)
        {
            String mensaje = "";

            foreach (var validationErrors in exc.EntityValidationErrors)
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    mensaje += validationError.ErrorMessage + "\n";

            MessageBox.Show(mensaje, "Se han encontrado errores", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
```

If I left textBoxNombre empty then the exception is triggered and the message box is shown.
Then I type some text in textBoxNombre but when I click on buttonAgregar again the exception is triggered and the message box is shown again with the same error message.
The buttonAgregar_Click() method don't get the new value in textBoxNombre.

How can I solve this?

Comment: This isn't a web application. This is a WPF application. Thanks.

Comment: is the exception same both times ? equal to "Debe escribir el Nombre" ???

Comment: ok, the code `db.SaveChanges();` seems to fail, and can you tell me what exception message are you getting  from the `catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException exc)`

Comment: @ Yasser The message is: Debe escribir el Nombre

Comment: are you sure that `Nombre` is getting a value, can you see that again ?

Comment: Hi, welcome. If an answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the previously created `Cliente` instance is still tracked by the context and when you call `SaveChanges` that entity also get validated. Hence you get the validation exception.

Detach the entity if you get any validation errors. You may also use new instance of the context each time the button is clicked.

```
private void buttonAgregar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cliente = new Cliente
    {
        Nombre = textBoxNombre.Text,
        Apellido1 = textBoxPrimerApellido.Text,
        Apellido2 = textBoxSegundoApellido.Text,
    };

    db.Clientes.Add(cliente);

    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException exc)
    {
        String mensaje = "";

        foreach (var validationErrors in exc.EntityValidationErrors)
            foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                mensaje += validationError.ErrorMessage + "\n";

        db.Entry(cliente).State = EntityState.Detached;

        MessageBox.Show(mensaje, "Se han encontrado errores", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now a question: Should I write db.Entry(cliente).State = EntityState.Detached; in a finally block? For performance. Thanks.

Comment: @user1537004 No. You need to detach it only when a validation exception is thrown.